# Image processing : detect high with camera

Tags: java, image, image-processing, optimization, detection

I have a camera that is pointing on a road. Right in boarder of this road, there is a big grey floor lamp. On this floor lamp i will paint some horizontal red lines.

I want to make a java application that can count the number of red lines.

I could simply get an image, with a for loop move on each pixel and show if it's red... but this will be really not optimized.  I can specify that the lines are perpendicular to the image. To optimize I could simply move in y in the center of the image and count each time the color goes from gray to red?

do you have any idea of library that i can use, or an image processing process that make it better ?

thanx for help

EDIT :

From that image : [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nThs4.jpg)

i can have this result : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khk2a.png)

how coul'd i count the number of line

Comment: I'd be inclined to try the simple solution first. Maybe it will be fast enough. At least it will provide a baseline against which to measure the performance and accuracy of other solutions.

Comment: I think it too... but... the system will be used to measure the snowdepth. there will perhaps have false positive ( red car) or some wrong mesure because of fog... 

Starting from this observation and telling me that a piece of painted wood was not necessarily pretty, I changed my approach a little bit. I made an application (openCV) of overlaying two images. The first one is my calibrated piece of wood that I put over a reference element. 

So I could process this new image directly. 

but the red line counting problem persists.

Comment: Can you post an example image (or set of example images)?

Comment: I've edit the main post with some images

Answer (score 0):

so at this moment i make some tries into my office.

[Consider this wall is a floor lamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu2B3.jpg)

[on this picture you can see the calibrated pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwIj0.jpg)

[And here you have the pattern used as overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5328X.jpg)

Each line is separted with 5cm. when it snows, the bottom lines will gradually be hidden. So I can count the number of lines from the top to define the height of the snow.

Comment: This is supposed to be an answer. If you have extra information, you should edit the question rather than using an answer for this purpose.